# Is it true that sorting strings is O(n^2logn)?

Tags: algorithm, big-o

I read the following:

> Sorting takes O(NlogN) so how it is O(N^2logN)??. What we miss here is
>   that comparison of two strings is not O(1); in worst case, it takes
>   O(N). So the final complexity is O(N^2logN).

Is this correct? I had always assumed that sorting was always O(NlogN) but now I feel a little thrown off because it has become O(N^2logN).

If someone could explain why it's O(N^2logN) that would be great.

Edit: quote taken from here: https://www.hackerrank.com/challenges/string-similarity/topics/suffix-array

Comment: What's the source? What's the context? Do you mean sorting a string (e.g. `cab` becomes `abc`) or a list of strings?

Comment: It's not really N^2, since one N is the length of the string and the other is the number of strings. If the strings are short in comparison to the number of strings, it converges to O(NLogN).

Comment: It depends on what `n` means. Is it the length of the string? Is it the number of strings? Is it the number of bits to represent the whole set of strings? My *guess* would be that if it is the latter then the time is O(nlogn) since either you have many short strings or few long ones, so the increase in the time of a comparison is repaid with the lower number of comparisons required.

Answer (score 33, accepted):

Think of it this way.

When you are sorting numbers, to detect which number is bigger, you need only *1 comparison*.

But when sorting strings, to detect which string is bigger, at times you need to compare all the characters of the string (i.e comparing `hello` and `hella` would need `5` `char` comparisons).

So in that case, every string comparison would take time that is directly proportional to the length of the strings. If the length is consistent, (suppose `l`), then the complexity would become `O(l*nlogn)`

---

Do not get confused between `n` and `l`. In any time complexity, `n` would stand for the number of inputs. In your case, complexity will be `O(n^2logn)` only when the length of the strings are also `n`.

Otherwise, taking the length of the strings as `l`, complexity would be `O(l*nlogn)`

Comment: Yes, but in that case the whole input would have size `n^2` (`n` strings of size `n`), so O(n^2logn) would still be quasi linear in the bit size of the input...

Comment: I do agree with your answer, but the same thing happens when sorting a list of lists of numbers (which is essentially the same concept as a a list of strings). In other words, a string is itself a list of characters. Thus, it's not just sorting a list that's `O(l*n log n)`, it's sorting a list of lists.

Comment: @VincentSavard, Yes, I agree. But I thought of answering in a way the OP has asked the question.

Comment: @Haris: Why assume that you always need to perform full string comparisons at every stage? For instance a quick-sort implementation may skip past any prefix known to common between the lower/upper bounds of the present range. I don't know what the complexity of an optimum algorithm is but I wouldn't be surprised if `O(n log n)` was possible.

Comment: You are referring to a specific sorting implementation. Note that sorting strings can be done in O(nl), it's NOT Omega(l*nlogn) problem.

Comment: @amit, which sorting algorithm can sort at `O(nl)`? If thats the case for strings then for integers it should be `O(n)`.

Comment: @Haris Radix sort, for example.

Answer (score 1):

You extracted that quote out of context; it's worth putting it back into context to understand what's going on.

The context is that we start with some string S of length N, and wish to sort the set of all possible suffixes of that string.

There are N possible non-empty suffixes, one for each character position, and the average size of a string in that set is (N+1)/2 (since every length from 1 to N is equally likely.)

If we assume that the expected cost of comparing two strings of average length L is O(L), and the expected number of comparisons to sort N objects is O(N log N), and finally since L is (N+1)/2, we can see that the expected time to comparison-sort *this particular set of strings* is O((N+1)/2×N×logN) which simplifies to O(N<sup>2</sup>logN).

But the expected cost of comparing two strings of length L is not actually O(L), because it is generally the case that it is not necessary to look at every character position in two strings in order to compare them. It is sufficient to look at the characters until the first non-match is found. If the strings are randomly distributed in the universe of possible strings, then the expected number of characters which need to be examined is actually O(1) (by a simple probabilistic argument), although the worst-case cost is O(L).

In the case of quicksort (at least), there is a counter-balance, which is the tendency for comparisons in later phases of the quicksort to be between strings which are closer together. In this case, the number of characters needed to be examined tends to approach log N, which is the expected length of the longest common prefix between two consecutive strings in a sorted uniformly-distributed sample of N strings.

So the actual expected cost of the sort should be O(Nlog<sup>2</sup>N).

As a further complication, it is possible to modify the quicksort algorithm to track the LCPs of each partition, which might help restore the expected number of comparisons to something smaller than log N.

(A similar argument can be applied to radix sort, which also eliminates the apparent O(L) term from the expected -- but not worst-case -- time. The cited article proceeds to provide a much better algorithm for the suffix tree problem, which avoids comparison-sorting.)

Comment: You are referring to a specific sorting implementation. Note that sorting strings can be done in O(n^2), it's NOT Omega(n^2*logn) problem.

Comment: @amit: if you read through to the end, you'll see that I claim that  sorting is expected O(Nlog^2N) with a comparison algorithm, which is less than O(N^2). Fortunately, the expected time of a radix sort is O(N), not O(N^2). I added some clarifications.